# Optimal Kernel Calculation of Largely Sparse Matrix

Tags: python, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I have a fairly large (1600,1600) sparse matrix B and I need to find its kernel (note: I know it to be 1dimensional, i.e. just one vector).

One approach is to "bruteforce" it by using `scipy.linalg.null_space()`. That is a fine way I would say, but for larger matrices it may not be the most optimal way. Therefore, I tried to implement my own method by using the sparse scipy library and svd

```
def kernel(matrix):
  # Convert the matrix to a compressed sparse row (CSR) format
  matrix = csr_matrix(matrix)

  # Calculate the singular value decomposition (SVD) of the matrix
  U, s, vh = linalg.svds(matrix, which='SM')
  ind = np.where(s == np.min(s))[0][0] # get the index of the vector with lowest singular value
  return vh[ind].T
```

The problem I am having is that the above code does return me a vector (which is nice), it is although far from being the kernel of B, as the norm of B times that vector is (firstly not constant, as it changes after every run) way larger than zero.
Anyone has ever encountered this problem? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Don't hold your breath on this.  It's unlikely that someone else has tackled the same problem, and less likely that such a person will see this question before it gets buried by newer questions.  While I have worked with scipy.sparse, I haven't tried anything like this, and wouldn't know how to evaluate the answer, dense or sparse.

Comment: With a good enough [mcve], someone who knows sparse, but not kernels, might be willing to help you debug your code.  As it stands, the function is not enough, except for someone who has tackled this before.

Comment: Thats unfortunate to hear

Comment: I have been stuck on this problem for a long time now. I thought that learning the theory behind svd would help, but it seems that it did not cut it :/